# Isometry in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Will there be an isometry in $\mathbb{R}^2$ taking the curve
>   $\alpha(t)=(\cos(t)+1, \sin(t)+2)$, where $t\in [0,\pi]$, to the curve $\beta
>  (t)=(t,\sin(t))$, where $t\in[0,c]$ and $c$ is a constant.

I know isometries preserves distances and curvatures. So when $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ then $$f(\vec{p})=A(\vec{p})+\vec{a},$$ where $\vec{a}\in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $A$ is an orthogonal transformation. Thus an isometry is a composition of a rotation and a translation.

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: @copper.hat I will rephrase it. Editing now.

Comment: Isometries also preserve invariants, e.g. curvatures.

Comment: @copper.hat Is that more clear?

Comment: A rotation or a _______.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin I edited that part too. Thanks.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Computing the curvatures will lead to a solution

Comment: Draw a picture.

Comment: A reflection is also an isometry.

Comment: @copper.hat I plotted it in wolfram and it looks like it is not an isometry. But how can I go about properly justifying it?

Comment: Lays, if you plotted it you can see that the first curve is a circle whose curvature is constant, and the second is a sinusoid that has a varying curvature. As it was noticed, isometries preserve the curvature, so these curves cannot be isometric.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin Thanks for explaining that. So I don't have to use matrices to justify it? Because this problem is a practice test question and I doubt my professor will let me justify it only by a graph.

Comment: Lays, I don't know exactly what your professor expects, but since this question is tagged "differential geometry" I suggested a relevant solution. Multivariable calculus people may do it differently.

Comment: Any isometry of normed vector spaces that maps $0$ to $0$ is linear. So any general isometry of normed vector space must be a linear map followed by a translation, i.e. an affine map.

Comment: @kahen Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @Lays It's a result by Mazur and Ulam from 1932. It's theorem 1 of [this paper](http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-17-3/17J3Mari.pdf). I just got home where I could find the title of the paper and dig the link up again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on @Yuri Vyatkin's answer: the initial point of the curve $\beta$ is an inflection point and therefore its curvature is 0, whereas all points of $\alpha$ have curvature 1. Hence the curves are not isometric.

The curvature $\kappa$ can be computed as the inverse of the radius $r$ of the osculating circle at the point. To find the osculating circle, consider three infinitely close points and use the unique circle through these three points. In the case of the sine curve the three points can be taken to be the origin, an infinitely close point $(t,\sin t)$, and the "symmetric" point $(-t, -\sin t)$. The three points lie on a line.  It follows that the radius of curvature is infinite and therefore the curvature is $0$.

Comment: Thanks user! I see that for $\alpha$ the curvature $\kappa = \frac{dT}{\alpha'(t)}$ is equal to $1$ like you said. For $\beta$ I having trouble getting the curvature. I got that $T(t) = \frac{\langle 1, cost \rangle}{\sqrt{1+cos^2t}}$ then if I divide $T'(t)$ by $\beta$ how can I get $0$?

Comment: @Lays, see my edit to the answer.